# how to test multiple sets of data using php unit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have a class and few functions that I need to test against multiple sets of data.  I load these data from flat files.  I understand that I can load a file in the setUp() method and run my tests, but how do I load multiple sets of data and test the same functions against those data?

Comment: How does that data look like and what kind of tests are you planning to execute?

Comment: It is an object and has lots of properties...I have serialized the object to a file, and I read it from it.  I have multiple files with different sets of data.  I need to read these files one by one, and execute the tests.

The functions do some calculations on these objects, mostly some addition.

Comment: Testing with random data breaks the actual goal of unit testing, which is to cover all the possible scenarios that a particular piece of code can be exposed to at runtime. This is achieved by explicitly testing units of code with the different possible inputs and comparing the outputs with the expected results (assertions). If your test methods need several whole objects to make those assertions then you're doing something wrong, or at least it falls out of the scope of unit testing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.
suppose  you wrote a function to add two numbers - wont you test it with multiple sets of data? In this case it is easy, because you are would be passing all your data to your add() function as parameters.

what if you need to load the data from a file?  Each file contains two numbers that need to be passed to your add function and test for summation?  My case is similar to this, just a bit more complicated than plain addition.

I dont think I am doing anything wrong, coding wise..just that I am trying to figure out how to test cases for it.

Comment: Ok, excuse me if I'm misunderstanding the situation. I'm trying to say that unit tests should be as explicit as possible, this includes avoiding dependencies on external resources / large sets of data, unless they are actually representing the persistence layer. Anyways, I've posted some sample test case. Is this approach applicable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $_testObjects = array();

    public function setUp() 
    {
        // load the files, unserialize the objects 
        // and store them in the $_testObjects array
    }

    public function getTestObjects()
    {
        return $this->_testObjects;
    }

    public function testA()
    {             
         foreach ($this->getTestObjects() as $obj) {
             // execute assertion/s
         }
    }

    public function testB()
    {             
         foreach ($this->getTestObjects() as $obj) {
             // execute assertion/s
         }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I did something similar already, thank you for the answer :)

Its almost the same, but instead of all files in the setUp() function, I loaded them individually inside each of my functions.  My objects are fairly heavy, so don't want to load all of them in one shot.

Thanks again.

Comment: 6 half dozen. I really think you should try testing loading them in one shot. What are you actually trying to test for? Deserialize/Some logic/Reserialize? Don't you actually have the source code files in which the objects are initially created? I would test with the original source code files.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [@dataProvider annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.dataProvider). That way, you don't need to loop on your own over the test data array.

```
class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $_testObjects = array();

    public function setUp() 
    {
        // load the files, unserialize the objects 
        // and store them in the $_testObjects array
    }

    public function getTestObjects()
    {
        return $this->_testObjects;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider getTestObjects
     *
     */
    public function testA($obj)
    {             
         // execute assertion/s
    }

    /**
     *
     * @dataProvider getTestObjects
     *
     */
    public function testB($obj)
    {             
         // execute assertion/s
    }

    // ...
}
```